# What is the inverse $z$ transform of $\frac{z}{(z^2+1)(z-1)}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Using partial fraction, the following is derived:

$$-\frac{1}{2}{\frac{z+1}{z^2+1}-\frac{1}{z-1}}$$

How can I transform the term $\frac{z+1}{z^2+1}$ into its $t$-domain?

I am having problem with this term as it can not be found in $z$-transform tables I am using.

Comment: $\frac{z+1}{z^2+1}=\frac{(i+1)/(2i)}{z-i}+\frac{(-i+1)/(-2i)}{z+i}$

Comment: Thank you. The term on the right hand side still have z in it. Does that mean I have to take the limit now to determine the inverse z transform of the term?

Comment: The terms on the right are terms that should appear in your table.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was helpful..